# Where to put builded nodejs application on my apache2 server

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, linux

I am building project which I want to deploy on my own static ip server (apache2). I am using postgresql database and python api (want to use it just as API not frontend), currently I am making frontend where I need to use node packages because I need to download and install OpenLayers for usage with OSM maps, when I build nodejs project I get dist/ directory which I need to put to production. I would like to know if it means that I can just put it to /var/www/html directory and if no please where should put it? Or please some explanation how it works :) Thank you very much.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the `/dist` directory in the `/var/www/html` directory is fine if it's a static build of the project, but it's recommended that you setup a virtual host so you can configure different sites served by a single Apache instance (e.g. you can run different projects on different sub-domains).

See [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-20-04) on setting up a virtual host on Ubuntu.